# How can I get a string from a gtk_combo_box item that was selected?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How can I get the string from a gtk_combo_box item that was selected?

For example, if a person selects fullscreen, I need to get the fullscreen string.

```
    GtkWidget *widget;
    GtkListStore *liststore;
    GtkCellRenderer *column;
    liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    widget = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, " ",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "fullscreen",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "windowed",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "640 x 480",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "720 x 480",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "1280 x 720",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "1920 x 1080",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "3840 x 2160",-1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(liststore, NULL, -1,0, "7680 x 4320",-1);
    column = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widget), 0);
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(widget), column, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(widget), column,"text", 0,NULL);
    g_signal_connect (widget, "changed", G_CALLBACK (set_screen_mode),NULL);
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using GtkComboBoxText? (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html)

Comment: I did not know GtkComboBoxText.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a simple text-only list like this, use a [GtkComboBoxText](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html) and get the text with [`get_active_text`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-get-active-text).

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you can click the green check mark on the left to accept it.